# TypeError in armstrong number program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code:

```
num=input("enter to check for armstrong num :   ")
num1=num
sum=0
while(num!=0):
      sum+=(num%10)**3
      num/=10

if(sum==num1):
      print(sum,"   is an armstrong number ")
else:
      print("go find another number")
```

And the output displayed:

```
enter to check for armstrong num    :   123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "armstrong.py", line 5, in <module>
     sum+=(num%10)**3
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `num` is a string, so `num%10` is invoking string formatting not modulo - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9792387/3001761.

Comment: Please don't type in error messages by hand. Copy and paste them directly from your terminal or console please.