# Python Program for finding Even or Odd using % giving error

Tags: python

I am new to python and this code is like ,why would it give me error. i came from java background so i am unable to understand why is this happening . i saw many answers but i cant understand what actually they are trying to say .

```
n=input("Enter a Number :")

if n%2==0:
    print("Even Number")
else:
    print("oddNumber")
```

Error I am Facing is  :

> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "Proj2.py", line 5, in <module>
>         if (n%2)==0 :
>     TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

Comment: Because `input` always returns a string. You need `n=int(input("Enter a Number :"))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792387/python-modulus-giving-string-formatting-errors

Comment: Welcome to python and stackoverflow. Whenever you got problems with your code the first thing you should do is to google your errors. This will most of the time will result in finding someone else in the past having the same errors as yours.

Comment: Yes , Thank you i am greatful

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your input to `int`, otherwise `input()` would just give you a string, e.g.:

```
n=input("Enter a Number :")
```

to become:

```
n = int(input("Enter a Number :"))
```